# State bug - row component getting bad values from props if wait

Tags: reactjs

I have a confusing state bug and wish to understand how it happens. I am not looking for a workaround, I already have one, but I wanted to understand this bug and actually fix it as it is defying my ability to think/reason in React. I was able to simplify my app and reproduce the bug in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/00no8bkw/7/

Clicking the "Delete" button will wait 10 seconds and then delete the row.

The bug is this:

1. Click "Delete" on row AAA
2. Wait 2 seconds
3. Click "Delete" on row BBB
4. Wait 8 more seconds and AAA row is deleted
5. Wait 2 more seconds and row BBB is deleted ***BUT the deleted row data AAA comes back into the data***

I am fetching the `rows` data fresh from the props as seen with `let { id, rows } = this.props` in `deleteEntry` after the `await wait(10000)`. We also see that `componentDidUpdate` has already triggered and rows did update. I even added a `this.updateid` property which I increment on `componentWillUpdate`, and the super weird thing is we see this is still at value of `0` even though it was incremented.

What is even more confusing then that is that if we "Delete" BBB row first, then "Delete" AAA row second, and wait 12 seconds, we see things properly delete and the deleted data of BBB does not come back.

Here is the code:

```
var setState;

async function wait(ms) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), ms));
}

class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateid = 0;
  }
  deleteEntry = async e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    await wait(10000);

    let { id, rows } = this.props;
    console.log('freshly fetched rows from props:', JSON.stringify(rows), 'updateid:', this.updateid);
    let rowsnext = rows.filter(({id:a_id})=>a_id !== id);
    setState({rows:rowsnext});
  }
  componentWillUpdate() {
    this.updateid++;
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    let { id, rows } = this.props;
    console.log(`this.props of row with id of "${id}" updated! this.props.rows is now:`, JSON.stringify(rows), 'updateid:', this.updateid);
  }
  render() {
    let { cells, id, rows } = this.props;
    console.log('cells:', cells)
    return (
      <tr>
        {cells.map(txt=><td>{txt}</td>)}
        <td><a href="#" onClick={this.deleteEntry}>Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    setState = this.setState.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    rows: this.props.rows
  }
  render() {
    let { rows } = this.state;
    return (
      <table>
        {rows.map(row=><Row {...row} rows={rows} />)}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table rows={[{id:'a',cells:['AAA']},{id:'b',cells:['BBB']}]} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the log output to console:

[image]

I put a green arrow on the `componentDidUpdate` log which says `"this.props of row with id of "b" updated! this.props.rows is now: [{"id":"b","cells":["BBB"]}] updateid: 1"`. This is good, I fully expect this re-render. However I put a red arrow next to `"freshly fetched rows from props: [{"id":"a","cells":["AAA"]},{"id":"b","cells":["BBB"]}] updateid: 0"` because this is back in `deleteEntry` after `await wait(10000)`. We see the "freshly fetched" are actually old props, even `this.updateid` is old, which is so weird. It should be connected live to `this.***` branch.

Deleting it in reverse, shows what I would expect, notice the two green arrows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the key prop when you iterate over the array so the DOM/state reconciliation doesn't notice the update:

In the table component change the return to:

```
<table>
 {rows.map(row=><Row key={row.id} {...row} rows={rows} />)}
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/00no8bkw/8/

You can read more about why keys are needed when creating elements from arrays here:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Note that you may not notice an issue immediately when you render without a key; it only happens when the array is mutated and React needs to determine if the DOM has changed.

If you use ESLint you can add these rules to help identify components that will need a key prop:

- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-key.md
- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md

Comment: Oh my goodness!!!! Thanks so much Alex!!!! If possible could you please explain in more detail the recociliation system with respect to how it was affecting this example. It would also help as three others replied without realizing this either (2 of them self-deleted their solutions).

Comment: If I had not used array map and instead had two rows manually typed out without a `key`, would this bug also hit? EDIT: just tested it out, the bug didn't hit - https://jsfiddle.net/00no8bkw/9/ - very interesting, I need to better understand the reconciliation system.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for your edits! I read those facebook articles long ago, and re-read them now, but I still feel I am not totally able to predict what will happen without keys, especially when state gets involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { render } from 'react-dom'

     async function wait(ms) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms))
    }

    const Row = ({ cells, id, deleteEntry }) => console.log('cells:', cells) || (
      <tr>
        {cells.map((txt, index) => <td key={index}>{txt}</td>)}
        <td>
          <a href="#" onClick={(e) => deleteEntry(e, id)}>Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )

    class Table extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          rows: props.rows,
        }
      }
      componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.rows !== nextProps.rows) {
          this.setState({ rows: nextProps.rows })
        }
      }
      deleteEntry = async (e, id) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.preventDefault()

        await wait(10000)

        const { rows } = this.state
        console.log('freshly fetched rows from props:', JSON.stringify(rows), 'updateid:', this.updateid)
        const rowsnext = rows.filter(({ id: a_id }) => a_id !== id)
        // let rowsnext = rows.map(row=>row);
        // rowsnext.push({id:'c', cells:['c', 'cc', 'ccc']});
        this.setState({ rows: rowsnext })
      }
      render() {
        const { rows } = this.state
        return (
          <table>
            {rows.map((row, index) => <Row key={index} {...row} rows={rows} deleteEntry={this.deleteEntry} />)}
          </table>
        )
      }
    }

    render(<Table rows={[{ id: 'a', cells: ['AAA'] }, { id: 'b', cells: ['BBB'] }]} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I updated your fiddle here. I think the code will work now. So, the problem with your code was that in the delete function, you were filtering out the row item based on the id but each time you were filtering from fixed props while you were updating the state and using the state to build the rows.

What i mean by that is, that you need to maintain one single source of truth here; which should be the local state in your case. 
So, when you update the rows in local state after filtering rows, you should have used the current row data from state.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much @shobhit1 but this is a work around. I do have a single source of truth, whenever state is updated, it updates the props. I am re-destructuring the data from the props after the `await wait(10000)`. The super interesting thing is, if we go in reverse delete order it works perfect. So your post here is a workaround. I really appreciate you trying though.